# Training keras model by loading different numpy files

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have multiple numpy files and I want to include them all into training. I wonder if it is possible to load anoter numpy file and continue training in the same epoch? Below is my working code. Currently it is training on one loaded numpy file.

```
   ####################################  Load Data #####################################3
patches_imgs_train  = np.load('patches_imgs_train_3.npy')
patches_masks_train = np.load('patches_masks_train_3.npy')

patches_imgs_train = np.einsum('klij->kijl', patches_imgs_train)
patches_masks_train = np.einsum('klij->kijl', patches_masks_train)


print('Patch extracted')

#model = M.unet2_segment(input_size = (64,64,1))
model = M.BCDU_net_D3(input_size = (128,128,1))
model.summary()

print('Training')

nb_epoch = 30

mcp_save = ModelCheckpoint('weight_lstm.hdf5', save_best_only=True, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=7, verbose=1, epsilon=1e-4, mode='min')

history = model.fit(patches_imgs_train,patches_masks_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=nb_epoch,
              shuffle=True,
              verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[mcp_save, reduce_lr_loss] )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, you can simply load the extra arrays before `model.fit` and then concatenate all the arrays as input data.
Otherwise, I'd recommend making use of the `keras.utils.Sequence` class to generate the input data.